# Grouped Product: Price and product list not showing on template

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, product-list, grouped-products

I've created a new grouped product and I've added 3 already created simple product in the associated product section.  I saved everything and go and view it on the website itself and there is no price next to the add cart button nor the included product list? Does anyone know of a fix for this.

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Comment: Try reverting to the default theme in order to localize the problem.

Comment: I know its the custom theme causing the issue, but I don't know what to look for after reverting back to the default theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your associated products have positive inventory (qty > 0) and set In Stock = True
2. Make sure the indexes are up to date (System / Index Management / Reindex all)
3. Try it on default theme (in System / Configuration / Design set package = "base" and theme="default") - if this is working on default theme, then the problem is in your custom magento theme.

Comment: Hey Thanks,

I went through your list, and is the theme giving me trouble.  I switched it back to default and the price and product list shows up immediately.  Do you have any idea where I should look in the theme code to fix this?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: there is a great tool for this purpose inside Magento backend. Go to System/Configuration, change "Current Configuration Scope" to "Website" or "Store View", then click on section "Template Path Hints" and enable them. You'll get an idea where to look.